# Making a Datatable's content appear in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am continuing my rewrite of an old VB6 into .Net as part of my .Net learning.  I have managed to read a CSV file into a Datatable, and I can view it has populated properly using the 'datatable visualiser' when I look at 'dt', but it doesn't seem to populate the DataGridView control I am trying to tie it to.   I have spent a couple of hours browsing other threads and trying things, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.    The DataGridView is on another form in the App, and I am reading the CSV file (a config file of sorts) from the main MDI form.    When I show the child form containing the DataGridView it is always empty  (it actually seems to have added the two datatable rows, but their content is all blank).

```
Public dt As New DataTable
Public ThisFilename As String = "c:\SitesDB.cfg"

Private Sub GetSitesDB()
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(ThisFilename)
        Dim newline() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn(newline(0)), New DataColumn(newline(1)), New DataColumn(newline(2)), New DataColumn(newline(3)),
            New DataColumn(newline(4)), New DataColumn(newline(5)), New DataColumn(newline(6)), New DataColumn(newline(7)), New DataColumn(newline(8)),
            New DataColumn(newline(9)), New DataColumn(newline(10)), New DataColumn(newline(11))})
        While (Not sr.EndOfStream)

            newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
            Dim newrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            newrow.ItemArray = {newline(0), newline(1), newline(2), newline(3), newline(4), newline(5), newline(6), newline(7), newline(8), newline(9), newline(10), newline(11)}
            dt.Rows.Add(newrow)
        End While
        Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt  ' data can be seen here using datatable visualiser hovering over 'dt'

    End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub
```

I have tried refreshing the DataGridView, to no avail.     I am wondering if its something to do with Form1.Show() being actioned after the datatable is tied to the DataGridView?

But the following didn't help

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        '  chkBit.Checked = False
        ' Dim cfgtext As String : cfgtext = ""
        DataGridView1.DataSource = NAMS.dt
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have continued to play with this problem, to no avail.   Can anybody please give me some guidance on what I am missing?